# Angular 5 ngx-imageviewer not working

Tags: html, angular, png

I am trying to add an image viewer canvas with zoom controls etc. [ngx-imageviewer](https://github.com/hallysonh/ngx-imageviewer) seems to provide what I need but I cannot get it to work as I get the following error when I try to do an AOT build with angular-cli

> 'client:157 Error during template compile of
>   'ImageViewerModule'Function calls are not supported in decorators but
>   'ɵmakeDecorator' was called in 'NgModule' 'NgModule' calls
>   'ɵmakeDecorator'.

When I try running with JIT I get the following error

> 'Error: StaticInjectorError[DomSanitizer]:
>   StaticInjectorError[DomSanitizer]: 
>       NullInjectorError: No provider for DomSanitizer!'

Has anyone been able to get this working or does anyone know of any other libraries that offer this kind of functionality? I only need it to support pngs

Answer (score 1):

i think you're trying to use a sanite url for your images src .. could it be? .. i so remeber to import it ..
if you don't ..so try to implement like this:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Pipe({
  name: 'safeHtml'
})
export class SafeHtmlPipe implements PipeTransform {

  constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) { }

  transform(value: any, args?: any): any {
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(value);
  // or
 // bypassSecurityTrustStyle(value: string): SafeStyle
 // bypassSecurityTrustScript(value: string): SafeScript
 // bypassSecurityTrustUrl(value: string): SafeUrl
  }

}
```

import it like:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,

    SafeHtmlPipe

  ],
```

use it like:

```
<img [src]="myUrl | safeHtml" />
```

Hope it helps you

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm still getting the same problem however. I think the problem could be with ngx-imageviewer itself since it still happens even when I pass no image to src

Answer (score 0):

I found an alternate npm package that I can get to work called [ngx-image-viewer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-image-viewer) (slightly different spelling)

Beware of a potential gotcha where you have to add an array of image urls rather than just the url string when adding the src input. e.g

```
<ngx-image-viewer  [src]="['imagePath']"></ngx-image-viewer>
```